# How to create your own approval custom workflow in spd 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I am using sp 2013. I would like to create some custom workflow in spdesigner. In this workflow I would like to create a task to userA. userA is a "sharepoint user/group column" After userA has approved I would like to create a task for userB. If userB has approved, the item must be published and visible for everyone.

I also have 2 requirement:

1) This option needs be enabled.

> Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited?

2) The items needs to be in draft version when they are uploaded. The draft version are only visible for the creator and the approvers.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds similar to something I'm doing, and have had a lot of issues with, due to the approval process no longer being in SharePoint Designer 2013.

However, your process is certainly possible doing something similar to the following:

- Create a 2010 workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013 to handle the end of the approval process. You can use the Content Approval task in a 2010 workflow. This will deal with publishing your document and making it visible to everyone.
- Create a 2013 workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013. In this workflow, you can "Start a Task Process", which will allow you to assign a task to more than one user (user A and user B), and choose the drop down for "Serial", as opposed to "Parallel". This will ensure user A needs to approve the item before user B is assigned a task to approve.
- If user B then approves the item as well, your 2010 workflow (created earlier) can be called from within your 2013 workflow to do the content approval and publishing of the document. You use the action "Start a List Workflow" to accomplish this.

To give an indication in stages:

**Stage One - Check Status**

Check the status of the document to ensure it's at draft (or whichever status you need) and assign this to a variable.
If the status variable is OK, go to stage two.
If it isn't, end the workflow.

**Stage Two - Document Approval Task**

Start a Task Process with users A and B in Serial. Ask them to review the document. Store the approval variable in Outcome.
If Outcome is Approved, go to stage three.
If it isn't, end the workflow.

**Stage Three - Publish the Document**

Start a List Workflow with your 2010 content approval workflow. 
Go to "End of Workflow".

This is just a simple example, but I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sequential approval rather than concurrent approval - so on approval by User A, it then passes a task to User B etc, rather than both User A and User B receiving approval tasks at the same time.  This is configurable on an out-of-the-box approval workflow (which I believe is available through the SharePoint UI) and is certainly something I have used before.

As for the required settings: Item 1 and Item 2 are both configurable in the library settings (and approvers should automatically be able to view the item anyway).  Plus, if the document is undergoing an approval process, the document should remain at "Pending" which is basically still "draft".

Comment: But what if I would like to create my custom, is it possible with the settings describer above?